# Run-time Error 438 trying to save output to excel

Tags: vba

I have next to no training with VBA and have primarily gotten by through copying existing scripts. I am attempting to Save a new file to a location on my drive and copied from a few lines that work well in another script. However, for this one in particular, I am getting the following error.

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Dim i As Long
Dim MyCounter As Integer
ReDim MyArray(1 To 4000) As String
Dim xlApp, xlWB As Object 
Dim ObjOutputBook As Workbook 
Dim strOutputPath As String 
Dim OutFileNum 

'Where file is saved
    strOutputPath = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\VBA Output\"

'initialize excel
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks '.Open(strInputPath)

'Output File

xlWB.SaveAs strOutputPath & "InnList_Add_Log" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hh-nn") & ".xlsx"
Set xlWS = xlWB.Sheets.Add
    xlWS.Name = "Load Code Log"
```

I am not sure what other information may be pertinent but I have not come across this before and nothing seems to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: What line in particular is giving that error?

Comment: I'm not getting the error. I did have to change the Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks line to actually .open an existing workbook.

Comment: The line with `xlWB.SaveAs`. I will try changing the line to use your recommendation and report back how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: Adding back the .open worked for me. Not sure why it wasn't working before but it is now. Thanks!